# how to get a full size from a page from a url

Tags: php, javascript

is possible (in php or javascript) get a full size from a page from a url?
with all images, js, and css

file_get_contents just give me the size of html

I need create a PHP that passing a URL by parameter return me the full size of this.

Many Thx

Comment: What do you mean 'full size'?

Comment: you have to find all files inside HTML (css, js, etc) then find sum()

Comment: i mean size in kilobytes,my problem is how to find all images and others files inside the html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to parse the page to work out all the dependencies that would be loaded, and check the sizes of each.

This would require a few steps. Luckily, opensource classes have been released to assist with this, take a look at:

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2223-PHP-Determine-the-size-of-Web-page-and-its-elements.html

This class should cover all the functionality you need.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your help, is exactly what i need, but, unfortunately this class don't work fine, a lot of people have the same error (and don't get answer from 2008 ) http://tinyurl.com/a9a6lr8